# How to remove the first word through out a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a file that i have read into a string array that looks something like this

```
string[] myArray = { "1x Car green", "2x Plane red", "3x boat blue","etc","etc" };
```

what i want to do is to remove numbers,the x and white space from everywhere in the string array, so the only thing left is something like

```
string[] myArray = { "car green","Plane red","boat blue"};
```

Comment: loop throught array , find first space in each , remove using substring or last index..

Comment: What would you do in the case of only one word, e.g. your example of "etc"?

Comment: @Devin, then find first space would be `null` or `0` and you would know that there is nothing to remove.

Comment: Agreed that would make the most sense, but the title of the question reads "remove the first word"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this -

```
myArray = myArray.Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf(' ') + 1)).ToArray();
```

**Assumption** - All words in your array starts with `Nx`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the fast answers, but this one solved it the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
myArray.map(function(e){ return e.substring(e.indexOf(' ') + 1) })
```

Comment: I just wrote the same thing in a much less cool way.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**Old school:**

```
 string[] myArray = { "1x Car green", "2x Plane red", "3x boat blue", "etc", "etc" };
 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
   {
     int indexOfSpace = myArray[i].IndexOf(' ')+1;
     if (indexOfSpace >= 0 && indexOfSpace < myArray[i].Length)
       myArray[i] = myArray[i].Substring(indexOfSpace);
   };
```

**Linq:** (like Rohit Vats slightly altered)

```
myArray = myArray.Select(x => x.Substring(Math.Max(0, x.IndexOf(' ') + 1))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone could most likely provide a better `regex`, but you get the idea.

```
string[] myArray = { "1x Car green", "2x Plane red", "3x boat blue", "etc", "etc" };
foreach (var item in myArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(item, @"([\d]{1,}x )", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It`s must solve your task.

```
            string pattern = "^(\\d*x* )";
            string[] myArray = { "1x Car green", "2x Plane red", "3x boat blue", "etc", "etc" };
            var result = myArray.Select(p => Regex.Replace(p, pattern, String.Empty).ToLower()).ToArray();

            foreach (string name in result)
                Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Comment: Your `regex` removes the `whitespace` characters from between the `vehicle` and `colour`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i`m update code. now it must work correct

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = myArray.ToList().Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"^.+?\s", "")).ToArray();
```